# How to calculate the minimum pumping length for some L?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

> Prove that the following language holds the pumping lemma for
> context-free languages: (Although it is not context-free)
>
> $L$ is a language under alphabet $\{a,b,c,d\}$
>
> $L = \{a^ib^ic^j \mid i,j \ge 0\}  \cup \{a^kb^kd^{2n}c^k \mid k,n \ge 0\}$
>
> Point out what is the smallest pumping length $m$ to which the pumping lemma holds.

I don't quite understand why the minimal pumping length is $2$, the only one character word in $L$ is $c$ and the pumping lemma holds for it.

and there's no other one character word in $L$ to my understanding. so shouldn't the minimal pumping lemma be 1?

Comment: The problem is not well-stated. If you mean "Prove that the following lemma fulfillss the conditions of the pumping lemma" then this cannot be done. Int first component, for $j=0$, any pumping in $a^ib^i$ will lead out of the language. The same in the second component for $n=0$. 2 is actually the smallest length where you can find words that cannot be pumped. For 0 and 1 you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: try pumping $z=abddc$ with $n=1$.

This is a little tricky. You should remember that the pumping length $n$ is used **twice** in the lemma. First, it is used to claim that any word such that $|z|\ge n$ can be pumped. This is not relevant here; indeed, $c$ can be pumped. But it has a second use, **limiting the size** of the "pumpable" segment, which fails here for $n=1$.

Let's assume $n=1$ and observe the word $z=abddc\in L$. We need to find $z=uvwxy$  such that $|vwx|\le n$ and $uv^iwx^iy\in L$.

Since $n=1$ then $vwx$ must contain of exactly one letter (at least one, since $|vx|>0$ and at most one because $|vwx| \le 1$). If we choose $v=a$ then $i=0$ would yield $bddc\notin L$ and similarly we can't have $v=b$ or $v=c$. Choosing $v=d$ seems the obvious choice, but then for $i=0$ we'll end up with $abdc\notin L$ becuase $d$ should appear an even number of times. So you need at least $n\ge 2$ in order to be able to pump an even number of d's.

Comment: Can't you just say that the minimal pumping length is equal to the number of states of the minimal $DFA$? (without the trash state)

Comment: @NimaJan This language is not regular and hence its minimal DFA is infinite.